# Converting multiple ranges to their own single column on another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

What I would like to do is copy a Range(B4:AD22) from "Sheet1" and paste all the values into a single column (B2) on "Sheet2." I will have to do this for multiple ranges and columns on Sheet2 i.e., Fromt "Sheet1": Range(B27:AD45), to column O2 on Sheet2.

I would the VBA where I can easily edit the source range and destination column on sheet2. Any help is appreciated.

This is the only code that I've seen that accurately does what I need it to do. My only problem is, I'm fairly new to VBA and don't know how to remove the "application" of this VBA code. I also don't need to select the range because it will always be constant, B4:AD22, B27:AD45, and so on. I also don't know how to make it so it accommodates multiple range selections within the same script. The code, in it's current form, also doesn't seem to support pasting the values on a second sheet either. Don't even know if it's possible.

```
Sub ConvertRangeToColumn()
'Updateby20131126
Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Rng As Range
Dim rowIndex As Integer
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set Range1 = Application.Selection
Set Range1 = Application.InputBox("Source Ranges:", xTitleId, Range1.Address, Type:=8)
Set Range2 = Application.InputBox("Convert to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
rowIndex = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Rng In Range1.Rows
Rng.Copy
Range2.Offset(rowIndex, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
rowIndex = rowIndex + Rng.Columns.Count
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: First thought, a good start might by using a For Each variable in Range, so declare a range object, myRng = Range("B4:AD22"), then declare a variant variable (myVar), then do a For Each myVar in myRng .  Keep a counter variable, then append the value to sheet2.  Sheet2.Cells(myCounter,2) = myVar.value  .

Comment: FWIW, your question probably got downvoted because you appear to be asking for someone to write a whole macro for you rather than showing what you've already attempted and asking for specific help. It's too bad none of the 4 downvoters left a comment. [This might be helpful.](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Sub Tester()
    ToColumn ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C3"), _
                         Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    ToColumn ActiveSheet.Range("B4:AD22"), _
                         Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")
End Sub


Sub ToColumn(rngIn As Range, topCell As Range)

    Dim rv() As Variant, n As Long, d, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim nR As Long, nC As Long, i As Long

    d = rngIn.Value
    nR = UBound(d, 1)
    nC = UBound(d, 2)
    n = nR * nC
    ReDim rv(1 To n, 1 To 1)
    i = 0
    For r = 1 To nR
    For c = 1 To nC
        i = i + 1
        rv(i, 1) = d(r, c)
    Next c
    Next r

    topCell.Resize(n, 1).Value = rv
End Sub
```